# Moreau Decomposition in Terms of the Proximal Operator of the Conjugate Function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

By the Moreau decomposition, $x = \text{prox}_{tf}(x) + t\cdot\text{prox}_{t^{-1}f^*}(x/t)$.

If $f$ is a closed, convex function, then is it equivalent to write $x = \text{prox}_{tf^*}(x) + t\cdot\text{prox}_{t^{-1}f}(x/t)$?

This second form seems more useful for applying the decomposition to get the proximal operator of $f^*$, given $f$.

Source: [L. Vandenberghe - The Proximal Mapping](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/proxop.pdf).

Comment: You don't need addtional hypotheses. Just do the change of variable $t \mapsto t^{-1}$ followed by $x \mapsto x/t$, and get your result.

Comment: Or apply the Moreau decomposition to $f^*$ instead of $f$.